# Error creating autoscaling scheduled action

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to stop and start EC2 instances mapped with ASG on a particular timeframe. I am getting access denied errors even after giving the role appropriate permissions.

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg" {
  availability_zones        = "${var.availability_zones}"
  name                      = "${var.environment}-airflow-asg"
  launch_configuration      = "${aws_launch_configuration.lc.name}"
  target_group_arns         = ["${aws_lb_target_group.lb_tg.arn}"]
  max_size                  = "${var.asg_max_size}"
  min_size                  = "${var.asg_min_size}"
  desired_capacity          = "${var.asg_desired_capacity}"
  health_check_grace_period = "300"
  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  vpc_zone_identifier       = ["${data.aws_subnet.app_subnet_0.id}", "${data.aws_subnet.app_subnet_1.id}"]
  force_delete              = true

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  tags = [merge(
    var.common_tags,
    map("Classification", "private"),
    map("Name", "${var.environment}-airflow-asg"),
    map("key", "Name", "value", "${var.environment}-airflow", "propagate_at_launch", true)
  )]
}
# Stop instances each weekday at 6pm
resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "asg_stop" {
  scheduled_action_name  = "${var.environment}-asg_stop"
  min_size               = 0
  max_size               = 0
  desired_capacity       = 0
  recurrence             = "00 18 * * MON-FRI"
  autoscaling_group_name = "${aws_autoscaling_group.asg.name}"
}

# Startup instance each weekday at 8am
resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "asg_start" {
  scheduled_action_name  = "${var.environment}-asg_start"
  min_size               = "${var.asg_min_size}"
  max_size               = "${var.asg_max_size}"
  desired_capacity       = "${var.asg_desired_capacity}"
  recurrence             = "00 08 * * MON-FRI"
  autoscaling_group_name = "${aws_autoscaling_group.asg.name}"
}
```

Error after executing `terraform apply`:

```
Error Creating Autoscaling Scheduled Action: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::12345678910:assumed-role/jenkins/AssumeRoleSessionOrchestration is not authorized to perform: autoscaling:PutScheduledUpdateGroupAction on resource: arn:aws:autoscaling:eu-central-1:12345678910:autoScalingGroup:bb231f2f-7336-471a-bba6-312969c65523:autoScalingGroupName/asg
    status code: 403, request id: dbc1da6e-ad34-11e9-8c30-bd488dac5c78

  on ../../modules/airflow/asg.tf line 51, in resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "asg_stop":
  51: resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "asg_stop"
```

My role has the following permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "RDSPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:*",
                "application-autoscaling:DeleteScalingPolicy",
                "application-autoscaling:DeleteScheduledAction",
                "application-autoscaling:DeregisterScalableTarget",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalableTargets",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingPolicies",
                "application-autoscaling:PutScheduledUpdateGroupAction",
                "application-autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
                "application-autoscaling:RegisterScalableTarget",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
                "cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms",
                "sns:ListSubscriptions",
                "sns:ListTopics",
                "sns:Publish",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:GetLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've confused the similarly named [`application-autoscaling`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_applicationautoscaling.html) and [`autoscaling`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awsautoscaling.html) IAM policies.

[Application autoscaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/APIReference/Welcome.html) is used for scaling ECS services and DynamoDB table read/write capacity among other things.

The other type, `autoscaling`, is the more standard EC2 autoscaling that scales out groups of instances and is what you need for autoscaling groups as you have there.

So to fix this just change the `application-autoscaling:*` actions to `autoscaling:*`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "RDSPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:*",
                "autoscaling:DeleteScalingPolicy",
                "autoscaling:DeleteScheduledAction",
                "autoscaling:DeregisterScalableTarget",
                "autoscaling:DescribeScalableTargets",
                "autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
                "autoscaling:DescribeScalingPolicies",
                "autoscaling:PutScheduledUpdateGroupAction",
                "autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
                "autoscaling:RegisterScalableTarget",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
                "cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms",
                "sns:ListSubscriptions",
                "sns:ListTopics",
                "sns:Publish",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:GetLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```